# How to pass the selected item to the next view?

Tags: sencha-touch, sencha-touch-2

I have a List when I tap a element I use my NavigationView to push the new View.

How can I pass the selected element to the view?

Here is my method:

```
onListItemTap: function(dataview, index, target, record, e, eOpts) {
    dataview.up('navigationview').push({
        xtype: 'step3',
        title: record.data.titel
    });
}
```

Comment: let me my answer helped you or not

Comment: yes, I accepted it 1min ago

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
onListItemTap: function(dataview, index, target, record, e, eOpts) {
    dataview.up('navigationview').push({
        xtype: 'step3',
        title: record.getData().titel,
        data : record.getData()
    });
}
```

And if you have step3 view like this and you can access data inside `tpl` like i showed below

```
Ext.define('MyApp.view.Step3', {
    extend: 'Ext.Container',
    xtype: 'step3',    
    config: {
        tpl: '<tpl for="."><h3>{titel}</h3><h5>{some other field in the record}</h5></tpl>'
    }
});
```

Also you can access the data inside Step3 view using `this.data`